# java.io.FileNotFoundException: jackrabbit-standalone.jar

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

I want to use Apache Jackrabbit as a file storage tool in my web-project. I don`t have experience in using Jackrabbit. I started with downloading jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar,and then try to run the standalone server with:

```
java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar --port 8099
```

I have the next message:

```
Welcome to Apache Jackrabbit!
-------------------------------
Using repository directory jackrabbit
Writing log messages to jackrabbit/log
Starting the server...
Apache Jackrabbit is now running at http://localhost:8099/
```

But, when I move to localhost:8099 in browser, I have:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /. Reason:
    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

I checked **jackrabbit.log** and it is empty, but **jetty.log** contains:

```
2015-12-23 02:52:25.862 INFO  [main] Slf4jLog.java:67                  Logging to Logger[org.mortbay.log] via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2015-12-23 02:52:25.873 INFO  [main] Slf4jLog.java:67                  jetty-6.1.x
2015-12-23 02:52:25.924 WARN  [main] Slf4jLog.java:76                  Web application not found jackrabbit-standalone.jar
2015-12-23 02:52:25.931 WARN  [main] Slf4jLog.java:89                  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@3f2a3a5{/,jackrabbit-standalone.jar}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jackrabbit-standalone.jar
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.resolveWebApp(WebAppContext.java:965) ~[jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.getWebInf(WebAppContext.java:800) ~[jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.configureClassLoader(WebInfConfiguration.java:62) ~[jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:457) ~[jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130) [jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115) [jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130) [jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224) [jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main.run(Main.java:173) [jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.standalone.Main.main(Main.java:60) [jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar:na]
```

I use Ubuntu 14.04, it works properly on Windows 7.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Stack trace shows that jetty is looking for wrong file name `java.io.FileNotFoundException: jackrabbit-standalone.jar`  while jar name is - `jackrabbit-standalone-2.10.1.jar'. Why is that happening only on Ubuntu needs to be investigated.

Comment: Can you try starting using shell script mentioned here [Jackrabbit-startup-script](https://github.com/sixty-nine/Jackrabbit-startup-script)? Do edit script as per Jar name & location etc.

Comment: Surprisingly, the problem was caused by location of the .jar file. It was located at 'Donwloads' folder.The problem is that , due to my interface language, folder`s name is made of non-latin symbols.